# How to Use BCP to Insert Quotation Marks as Field Value Delimiters?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, bcp

I'm using BCP Utility in SQL Server 2016 to produce text files.  I have added a new entry in the batch file as follows:

```
bcp "%1..UI_CPT_Descriptions_Spanish" out "%2\OutGoing_Data\PROD.FMC2.CPTLANGUAGES.txt" -q -T -c -q -S DB403D  >>%2\%1Export.log
```

I need to ensure that each field is surrounded by quotation marks " but need guidance on the proper syntax to do this using BCP.

Comment: My advice: don't. The bcp utility is great for server-to-server transfers of native format data, but painful for most other use cases. If you're wanting to produce quoted CSV (or other quoted delimited) files consider using PowerShell and its `Export-Csv` cmdlet.

Comment: Field *terminators* (not delimiters) don't work that way and `bcp` cannot produce valid CSV output. In particular, the quote could only *separate* values, meaning that a single value would never be surrounded by quotes -- and even where it was, quotes inside a value would not actually be escaped.